# how to make java program detect changes to a file?

Tags: java

I have Program that reads and displays the colour in a `jLabel`, based on its input supplied by a input.txt file. 
My doubt is that, is my program is able to  read the updates supplied by the input.txt file?

The input.txt is file supplied by linux keeps updating o/p will be either 0 or 1.

```
0 - display red.
1 - display green.
```

I am able to read very clearly & display the output. But if the input is changed by any means manual/auto this program needs a restart to display this change in the input.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement a file watcher that warns you about changes in files, here is some Oracle's documentation about how to do it for a directory: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html.